# How can i use External Content Types - SQL Authentication with NO Kerberos

Tags: bcs

I'm in the process of using ECT and the data is in a sql sever.
Before i get started is this possible with no kerberos existing in this current environment.
So the service where SP resides is different from the Sql Server service.
Can i use a slq server login with ECT.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Secure Store Service if you don't want to use kerberos.

Check this out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee556780.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. Follow the steps in [this blog post](http://wyldesharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/setting-up-external-content-type-for.html) for more information.